# Why the number of "Environment.NewLine" remains the same even if I go up one line?

Tags: c#, newline, richtextbox

I am trying to create my on text editor using VS2013 and C#. To create the text area I am using a `RichTextBox`. I trying to add also a sidebar (`TextBox`), which counts (increases and decreases) the number of lines in the `RichTextBox` whenever the user clicks enter or whenever it goes up one line.

My problem is that, I have noticed, the `System.Environment.NewLine`, that **was automatically previously added** to the `RichTextBox` (whenever the user clicks Enter), still remains on the `RichTextBox`, even if I go up one line.

Do you see any errors/typos in my code?

```
    private void newLineDown_EventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs ea)
    {
        //Other if statement

        else if (ea.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            // If the number of lines in the RichTextBox decreased, 
            //I could rewrite the lines in the TextBox
            if (this.textBox1.Lines.Length < rows)//WRONG: 
              ///In fact, I have to control the number of lines in richTextBox1!!
            {
                    this.textBox1.Text = "";//Clearing the TextBox

                    --rows;//Decreasing the count variable

                    //Redrawing the numbers that represent the number of lines.
                    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
                    {
                        this.textBox1.Text += i.ToString();
                        this.textBox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
                    }
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Well if you don't remove the line then it will still count as one line, obviously.

Comment: But the other chars are removed, why the NewLine not?

Comment: You should add some code that allows people to reproduce it since your question isn't clear about what you're trying to do (at least not to me).

Comment: The code you've added doesn't help. It looks like a snapshot of your code during your attempts to debug the issue. However it's still a bit unclear what do you expect to happen under what conditions. What does the "This is garbage" comment mean? The `for` loop will make the `TextBox` contain all number from `1` to `rows` so even for few lines it would've to be a very big `TextBox` to see it changes the value at the end. Didn't you mean just `this.TextBox.Text = i.ToString()` without the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `this.TextBox.Text = rows.ToString()` :)

Comment: Do not consider the garbage, it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: I mean that inside the loop, yes, actually I would like to write the number of the line vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could just handle the `TextChanged` event like so

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Lines.Length.ToString();
}
```

This should automatically update the number of lines there are in the RTB, including when you delete characters.

Comment: Thanks, you made me understand I was counting the number of lines of the textBox1 and not of the richTextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error: I was controlling the number of lines of the textBox1 and not of the RichTextBox:

```
private void TextChanged_EH(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = "";

   /* When the cursor is on the first line, 
     Count() returns 0, 
  but I still want to write 1 on the first line of the textBox1 */
    if(this._rtb.Lines.Length == 0)
        this.textBox1.Text += '1';

    for (int i = 1; i <= _rtb.Lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text += i.ToString();
        this.textBox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```